# parse Scala List[Int] from JsObject

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, json

I need to parse a List`[Int]` values from `JsObject`. I have get the normal  `String` and `Int` values from `JsObject` by below code.

**What I get**

```
def receive = {
    case json_req: JsObject =>  {

        val studentName = (json_req \ "student_name").as[String]
        val studentNo = (json_req \ "student_no").as[Int]  

     println("studentName"+student_name)
     println("studentNo"+student_no)
    }
  }
```

this above code prints the Student name as well as student no.

**What I need**

*JSONObject*

```
{"student_records":[
{"student_id":9,"class_id":9},
{"student_id":10,"class_id":10},
{"student_id":11,"class_id":11}
]}
```

from the above `JsonObject` I need to get the two list values likely student ids List and class ids List

```
StudentList = List[9,10,11]
ClassList = List[9,10,11]
```

**What I tried**

```
def receive = {
    case json_req: JsObject =>  {
      try {

         val StudentList  = (json_req \ "student_records" \\ "student_id").map(_.as[Int]).toList
          val ClassList  = (json_req \ "student_records" \\ "class_id").map(_.as[Int]).toList    

          println("StudentList = "+StudentList)
            println("ClassList = "+ClassList)

      } catch {
        case e: Exception => println(e)

      }
    }
  }
```

my tried code gives  this `Exception`

```
 play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(Valid
ationError(error.expected.jsnumber,WrappedArray())))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the same "JSONObject" string that you used in your question then your code will work as you expect (although you shouldn't use Title Case unless it is a constant).

The error that you see is because one of values that you expect to a number isn't really a `JsNumber`.  Maybe it's undefined, maybe it's a string, maybe a null or maybe even an array.  If it's a string then it may still be an Int, you just need to parse it properly.  What you can do to make your code more flexible and to give you a better indication of what went wrong is to manually process the `JsValue`.  If you look at the `jsValueToInt` method below, you can see how to take ht `JsValue` and convert it to an Int manually.

```
// notice that the class_id: "10" is actually a String in this version
val json_req = Json.parse(
  """
    |{"student_records":[
    |{"student_id":9,"class_id":9},
    |{"student_id":10,"class_id":"10"},
    |{"student_id":11,"class_id":11}
    |]}
  """.stripMargin)

def jsValueToInt(jsval: JsValue): Int = jsval match {
  case JsNumber(x) => x.toInt
  case JsString(s) => s.toInt // may throw a NumberFormatException
  case anythingElse => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"JsValue cannot be parsed to an Int: $anythingElse")
}

val studentList = (json_req \ "student_records" \\ "student_id").map(jsValueToInt).toList

val classList  = (json_req \ "student_records" \\ "class_id").map(jsValueToInt).toList
```

Comment: Thanks friend as you said my posted  code is working fine I have found the issue in my side.I called another `method` instead of needed method so it throws `exception`.